# handling state between landscape and portrait in android

Tags: android

I have a problem while developing application using layout and layout-land, the data is not maintain between those two layout. please help me. i also tried onConfigured().

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);   
}
```

Comment: What data?  Persisted settings? Local variables...?

Answer (score 2):

When the device orientation changed, the onCreate event is called again.  You need to save any information that you have into a bundle on the onSaveInstanceState and reload it again on the onCreate event.

Code for OnCreate

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  if(savedInstanceState!= null)
  {
    restoreDataFromBundle(savedInstanceState);
  }
}
```

Code for onSaveInstanceState

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
  outState.putString("key", "value");  
  super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Code for restoreDataFromBundle

```
private void restoreDataFromBundle(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   String myString = savedInstanceState.getStringArray("key");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare this also in your manifest file if you would like to handle the screen changes yourself.
Add this to your activity in AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```